# Java if statement won't run - Testing to see if a substr(0,1) is == 00

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, text-files, random-access

I have a Random Access file that holds records in this format `"00,          ,  "` - What I'm trying to do is read from the random access file and check to see if there are entries at a particular position ( As written in the code below ). Reading the records is fine but when It reads a record with a `substr(0, 1)` it will still output the `text field GUIS which would normally hold the values I need (Date, Hour, and Client Name)`. I've tried changing `substr` to `values[0]` which is an array that splits up the variable holds the value of the particular `position` they searched for. `s - This is the variaable that holds the line`

### My Java FILE - fileWriter.txt the randomAccess file

```
public class readRandomDataFile extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    
    private static Path file = Paths.get("fileWriter.txt");
    private static String s = "00,          ,  "
            + System.getProperty("line.separator");
    private static FileChannel fc = null;
    private static int RECSIZE = s.length();
    
    
    
    private static JButton submit;
    private static JLabel output;
    private static JLabel bankDetails;
//    private static JTextField txtClient = new JTextField("", 20);
    private static JTextField txtDate = new JTextField("",6);
    private static JTextField txtClient = new JTextField("",15);
    private static JTextField txtHour = new JTextField("",6);


//    private static JTextField txtHour = new JTextField("",6);
    
    private static JLabel lblClient = new JLabel("Client");
    private static JLabel lblDate = new JLabel("Date");
    private static JLabel lblHour = new JLabel("Hour");
    private static JLabel noResult = new JLabel("");
    private static JLabel lblHeading1 = new JLabel("<html><h1>Meeting Calendar</h1></html>");
    private static JLabel lblHeading2 = new JLabel("<html><h2>Enter this months appointment</h2></html>");
    
    private int date;

    
   public readRandomDataFile(){
        super("Read Date File");
        setSize(300,300);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        
        
        output = new JLabel();
        submit = new JButton("Submit");
        
        bankDetails = new JLabel();
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        
        add(lblHeading1);
        add(lblHeading2);
        
//        add(lblDate);
//        add(txtDate);
//        txtClient.addActionListener(this);
        
        add(lblDate);
        add(txtDate);
        txtDate.addActionListener(this);

//        add(lblHour);
//        add(txtHour);
//        txtHour.addActionListener(this);
                
        
        add(submit);
        submit.addActionListener(this);
        
        add(output);
           
   
    } 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        date = Integer.parseInt(txtDate.getText());
        Object source = e.getSource();
        
        String strID = "";
        
        if(source == submit){
            byte[] data = s.getBytes();
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
            try{
                fc = (FileChannel)Files.newByteChannel(file, READ, WRITE);
                strID = txtDate.getText();
                    buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
                    fc.position(date * RECSIZE);
                    fc.read(buffer);

                    s = new String(data);
                    
                    String[] values = s.split(",", -1);
                    if(s.substring(0,1).equals(00)){
                        noResult.setText("No Results Found");
                    }
                    else{
                            output.setText(values[0]);
                            output.setVisible(false);
                            add(lblClient);
                            add(txtClient);
                            add(lblHour);
                            add(txtHour);
                            txtClient.setText(values[1]);
                            txtHour.setText(values[2]);
                       //output.setText("Info for ");
                    }
                fc.close();            
            }
            catch(IOException er){
                System.out.println("Error connecting to or reading to file");
            }
        }
        }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        readRandomDataFile one = new readRandomDataFile();
        one.setVisible(true);

//        int id;
//        String strID = "";
//        double fee;

        }
    
       }
```

Comment: `0` is the same as `00` and *neither* are equal to `"0"` (the result of substring-the-first-character on a string that beings with a zero..)

Comment: I have actually done 'substr(0,1) == "00"' and it didn't work either. Have you got any idea what parts of the code I should change to get the if statement to work?
Thanks @user2864740

Comment: `"0".equals(0)` <- always false. But since `equals` *should* be used for comparing strings, how can it be fixed?

Comment: @user2864740 - Oh great. I realised that substr actually cuts out one of the numbers so it's instead "0" not '00'... I changed it to substr(0,2)

Comment: `"00".equals(00)` (same as `"00".equals(0)`) <- always false as well, for the same reason. Hint: compare two *strings*.

Comment: Change the comparison expression as follows s.substring(0,2).equals("00")

Answer (score 1):

What fixed this was simply changing the

```
 if (s.substring(0,1).equals("00")) {
     noResult.setText("No Results Found");
 }
```

TO - I changed the substr(0,1) to (0,2)

```
if (s.substring(0,2).equals("00")) {
    noResult.setText("No Results Found");
}
```

and also added the GUI for noResult to the JFRAME `add(noResult)`